# C# Windows Forms and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have to send my C# Windows Forms project (using SQL Server LocalDB on vs server explorer) to my teacher but if I send her my project with localDB as my database, it doesn't work on her system. What should I do? I really appreciate it if someone helps me.

Comment: I suggest dropping SQL Server and using SQLite instead as it uses a file to store the DB data. For this to work on a different machine, the localDb would have to be set up there too, which is probably not something you can do.

Comment: *Why* isn't it working on her system?  Is it because she doesn't have SQL Server or is that a specific error that she is receiving?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a proper error description, please be clear

Comment: she doesn't get any errors,I mean cause she doesn't have my database which I created locally,the project doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same scenario. I just did in this manner,

1. Create a database on SQL Server Management Studio and add all the tables and funcs to it
2. Just copy and paste the created database from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\YourDatabase.mdf and YourDatabase_Log.ldf files to your debug folder.
3. Lastly, Change your SQLConnection String to connect the database on the location of the `CurrentFolder` which of format,

> Connection String

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
string databaseName = "YourDatabaseName.mdf";
string fullpath = path + @"\" + databaseName;
if (File.Exists(fullpath))
{
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
  Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + path + @"\" + databaseName + 
  "");
 return con;
}
else
{
  throw new Exception("Database Not Found :(");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send your database script to your teacher. You can do for Microsoft Sql Server like that:

Right click on your db > Tasks > Generate Scripts... > next > next > Advanced > You should change "Types of data to script" area as "Schema and data". > Click "Open in new query window" radio button. > next > next > finish.

After this process, you can save this script file and send to your teacher.

Comment: thanks for your helping! I really appreciate it. And I have to mention other thing, I created my database in microsoft visual studio,in server explorer part,here can I do what you said ?

Comment: This process what i wrote can work on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I don't know a method for vs server explorer.