# Why I need to install sql server while deploying my .NET application?

Tags: .net, sql-server, deployment, setup-deployment

I want to know is it compulsory that i install SQL server 2008/12 while deploying my app , what i want is that there must be .mdf and .ldf file present in my app data that used for transaction operation is it possible with out installing sql servver or some of its component

its is a huge setup of 5gb or 240mb of SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU how to get rid if that

**focus on:**

and also tell me if necceary to install then what components or setup should i install and have less size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366586/is-it-possible-to-run-a-mdf-database-without-sql-server-program-c

Comment: actually they are saying to install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23650 that is with management studio and is of 240MB is there any solution available that we donot install management studio and only install its services or instance while deployment simply less size then that one

Comment: I NEED THAT ANSWER TOO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple use local database that read ldf and mdf file by Using data directory
In connection string and 
Mdf and ldf file in bin/debug folder
And convert database to sql server database file
It's a local dB then use this link to publish
[publish a project with local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321508/publish-a-project-with-local-database)